# Automapper - map two objects that have the same type

Tags: c#, generics, automapper

I have two dto classes:

```
public class JourneyResponseDto
{
    public short Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public JourneyStatusEnum Status { get; set; }
    public JourneyTypeEnum Type { get; set; }
    public short? StaticSegmentId { get; set; }
    public short? DynamicEventId { get; set; }
    public long? StartTime { get; set; }
    public string BusinessUnit { get; set; }
    public long CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public long CreateDate { get; set; }
    public long? UpdatedBy { get; set; }
    public long? UpdateDate { get; set; }
}

public class JourneyDetailsResponseDto : JourneyResponseDto
{
    public List<JourneyTreeResponseDto> JourneyTrees { get; set; }
}
```

In my Automapper I create a map from entity to base dto response and map each member:

```
        CreateMap<Journeys, JourneyResponseDto>()
            .ForMember(dto => dto.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.Id))
            .ForMember(dto => dto.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.Name))
            .ForMember(dto => dto.Description, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.Description))
            .ForMember(dto => dto.Status, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => (JourneyStatusEnum)x.StatusId))
            .ForMember(dto => dto.Type, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => (JourneyTypeEnum)x.TypeId))
            .ForMember(dto => dto.StaticSegmentId, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.StaticSegmentId))
            .ForMember(dto => dto.StartTime, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.StartTime.ToEpoch(true, offsetMinutes)))
            .ForMember(dto => dto.BusinessUnit, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.BusinessUnit))
            .ForMember(dto => dto.DynamicEventId, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.DynamicEventId))
            .ForMember(dto => dto.CreateDate, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.CreateDate.ToEpoch(true, offsetMinutes)))
            .ForMember(dto => dto.UpdateDate, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.UpdateDate.ToEpoch(true, offsetMinutes)))
            .ForMember(dto => dto.CreatedBy, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.CreatedBy))
            .ForMember(dto => dto.UpdatedBy, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.UpdatedBy));
```

I want to create map for Journeys to JourneyDetailsResponseDto but I want to avoid the code repetition above.

If I do :
CreateMap(Journeys, typeof(JourneyResponseDto)) I get error

> Journeys is a type, which is not valid in the given context

If I do:
CreateMap(typeof(Journeys), typeof(JourneyResponseDto)) I get error for each member of the entity

> "Object does not contain a definition for Id and no accessible
> extension method 'Id' accepting a first argument of type 'object'
> could be found ( are you missing a using directive or an assembly
> reference)

I was thinking on an extension methods but now I would rather try to do a generic method on those two types and use it.

So far I managed to do this:

```
private IMappingExpression<Journeys, JourneyResponseDto> MapJourneyToResponseDto(int offsetMinutes)
{
    return CreateMap<Journeys, JourneyResponseDto>()
        .ForMember(dto => dto.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.Id))
        .ForMember(dto => dto.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.Name))
        .ForMember(dto => dto.Description, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.Description))
        .ForMember(dto => dto.Status, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => (JourneyStatusEnum)x.StatusId))
        .ForMember(dto => dto.Type, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => (JourneyTypeEnum)x.TypeId))
        .ForMember(dto => dto.StaticSegmentId, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.StaticSegmentId))
        .ForMember(dto => dto.StartTime, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.StartTime.ToEpoch(true, offsetMinutes)))
        .ForMember(dto => dto.BusinessUnit, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.BusinessUnit))
        .ForMember(dto => dto.DynamicEventId, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.DynamicEventId))
        .ForMember(dto => dto.CreateDate, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.CreateDate.ToEpoch(true, offsetMinutes)))
        .ForMember(dto => dto.UpdateDate, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.UpdateDate.ToEpoch(true, offsetMinutes)))
        .ForMember(dto => dto.CreatedBy, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.CreatedBy))
        .ForMember(dto => dto.UpdatedBy, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.UpdatedBy));
}
```

However, I am unable to use JourneyDetailsResponseDto as any typeof usage here throws the above errors.

Comment: From the answer's comments "_We have to explicitly list them as in the past , a change of a name in a property in dto or entity potentially breaks the app._". What I would do is remove all unnecesary (as in automatically mapped) properties and create an interface for the `Journeys` class. If you do and as soon as the reference is updated, the code would not compile avoiding breaking the app. The class would not implement the expected interfece and you will be able to adapt the code to those unspected changes.

Answer (score 1):

Since `Journeys` and `JourneyResponseDto` have same property names there is no need to write `.ForMember()` for each property, mapper will map them automatically.

```
CreateMap<Journeys, JourneyResponseDto>();
```

Comment: That does not work... I need to CreateMap<Journeys, JourneyDetailsResponseDto>() and I need to use the same members I used above but I want to avoid code repetition

Comment: Use them how, **all** members will be mapped automatically, you don't need to specify them with `ForMember()`.

Comment: @grozdeto long time I dont use it, but iirc automapper by default maps the properies with the same name, so you could avoid lines like `.ForMember(dto => dto.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.Id))`. Others where there is casting os names change you should map them.

Comment: @RandomSlav not all properties are straighforward.  Some properties need mapping and there are also type castings.

Comment: @Cleptus I understand how automapper works, however, we are a startup and as a business the properties offer change names. We have to explicitly list them as in the past , a change of a name in a property in dto or entity potentially breaks the app.

Comment: @Cleptus you are right, he should write `ForMember()` only for properties like `Status`, `Type` etc...

Comment: @grozdeto then write unit test for mapping. In quite a lot of cases [`AssertConfigurationIsValid`](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Configuration-validation.html) is enough.

Comment: @Cleptus shouldn't automapper handle enum type castings out of the box? Also I believe there are options to handle some conversions without need to manually specify them for every property, but I will need to refresh my knowledge in this part.

Comment: @grozdeto **"we are a startup and as a business the properties offer change names"**. Can you elaborate on this a bit further. I'm just curious, why do you change name of properties often? Is the word "offer" a typo?